# ASP MVC 4 changing items in a list as user types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a web application with ASP MVC4 application. I am also using the TwitterBootstrapMVC api. I am trying to make a view where I have a drop down list at the top along with a text-box. Below, is a table of people. The drop down list will contain the column headers of the table. Once the user selects a column in the drop down list, they can then type into the text-box to narrow the results in the list of items in the table below.

For example. The table has many people in it. The user then selects "Last Name" in the drop down list. He then proceeds to type Smith into the text-box. As he types every character, the table's results are narrowed by only displaying people with a "s" in their last name. When the "m" is typed into the text-box, the list of people are narrowed to only show people with "sm" in their last name etc.

I know how to make the table, text-box, etc. I do not know how to make the results in the table change as I type in the text-box without reloading the page.

Comment: you need ajax for that, you will need some javascript too, need an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's ajax and an action method that returns a partial view containing the searched data and your html table strucutre. Here's a short sample:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchTerm){
    var model = db.Users.Where(u => u.LastName.contains(searchTerm));
    return PartialView("_Students", model);
}
```

**Script**

```
$("#textBoxId").on("keyup change", function() {
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    $.get("/Controller/Search", { searchTerm: searchTerm }, function(data) {
       $("#tableId").html(data);
    });
});
```

You just need to add another parameter to your action method for checking what was selected in the dropdown.

Read this for more: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Wouldn't going back to the controller refresh the page?

Comment: No. That's the purpose of $.get, it allows you to call methods in your server without refreshing your page.

Comment: Im not familiar with the script code you provided. I am using razor as my view engine also. Where would I add in the script code? Into the View somehow?

Comment: That script was written in jQuery. It works with razor. Put it in a js file then you may add it to your script bundle or your main view. It seems you are not familiar with jQuery? check the link that I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to implement is an autocomplete textbox. [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) has a nice one. It is fairly simple to implement.

Or you can try out the [ASP.NET AJAX Control toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete.ashx). I haven't tried this one myself, so I'm not sure how simple/friendly it is.

Comment: not quite. I want the texbox to simply narrow the results in the table of people.

Comment: That's what an autocomplete textbox does. It's a textbox that, when typed in, pops up a list of available options, narrowing them as you type. Unless I am misunderstanding your question.